# EF 6.1 code first will not detect column changes

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, ef-fluent-api

I am working on a web api project using EF 6.1.3 (code first) fluent API and SQL Server 2008 R2. I create  migrations in code using `add-migration` and I have been able to create several migrations with no issues. Now I made a change to the model (increased column size for three columns in different tables) as follows:

```
Protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    ... //previously these columns had length = 50
    modelBuilder.Entity<EvalDef>().Property(t =>t.Name).HasMaxLength(70); 
    modelBuilder.Entity<ProgDef>().Property(t => t.Name).HasMaxLength(70);
    modelBuilder.Entity<ReqDocDef>().Property(t => t.Name).HasMaxLength(70);
    ...
}
```

I am using the `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` initialization:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new 
      MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<FtoContext,FTO.Model.Migrations.FtoConfiguration>());
}
```

Now when I run the `add-migration` command (from PM console), EF will not detect the changes to the model and an empty migration is created. I can't figure out why the fluent api model changes are not noticed when creating the migration.

Also, when I run the app, the `OnModelCreating` method is executed but I do not get any exception...which I would expect since now the DB schema would not match the current model.

Comment: Have you tried doing a Rebuild? Maybe EF is using an old version of the assembly...

Comment: Are the column sizes correct in the database?  Do you have auto migrations on?

Comment: What do you mean by correct size? as stated in the sample code, original size for the columns is 50.

Comment: I meant you actually checked the database pointed to by the connection string to make sure it is still 50. If you have automigrations on, it would update behind the scenes. Try adding a temp column to your model and see if it picks things up.

Comment: Having the same problem with EF 4.3.1 and VS2015. I use the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion but after ADDING a column it does not detect changes. I worked ok in VS2012, which version are you using?